# Problem with replace content of div in React JS or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two components for ex. `<A/>` and `</B>`  and additionally `<div id='test'>`.
After pressing the button ,,A1",i want insert the content of component `<A/>` into  and after pressing the button ,,B1" i want insert the content of component  into the `<div id='test'>`
Very important: After pressing buttons the previous value in `<div id='test'>` must be deleted and replaced with the new value.
How can i do it?

Best regards,
Łukasz

I tried this, but the commands not delete previous value.

```
ReactDOM.createPortal(<A />, document.getElementById('test'));
ReactDOM.createPortal(<B />, document.getElementById('test'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a `true` and `false` state for creating each of the portals. See below. I created two states and set them to `false` at the beginning:

```
const [mountedA, setMountedA] = useState(false);
const [mountedB, setMountedB] = useState(false);
```

When clicking on a button `A1` or `B1` you can run a function like below to set the desired state for each corresponding portal to show them or if the other one is visible, set its visibility to false:

```
const handleClickBtnA = () => {
  setMountedA(true);
  setMountedB(false);
}

const handleClickBtnB = () => {
  setMountedA(false);
  setMountedB(true);
};
```

And finally you could run this logic for returning each of the portals:

```
return mountedA
        ? ReactDOM.createPortal(<A />, document.getElementById("test"))
        : null;

return mountedB
        ? ReactDOM.createPortal(<B />, document.getElementById("test"))
        : null;
```